# AWK - explanation for example

Tags: awk, system

I have a file **1**:

```
1
2
3
```

This command prints:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("cat " 1)}'
1
2
3
```

.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{system( "cat '\''" 1 "'\''") }'
1
2
3
```

I changed the filename from "**1**" to "**one**"

I have a file **one**:

```
1
2
3
```

Now, the command does not work:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{system("cat " one)}' 
|
```

.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{system( "cat '\''" one "'\''") }'
cat: : No such file or directory
```

Why now commands do not work?

Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your file name is a number, you could write the number in system() directly, awk will convert it into string value internally. you even could write expression to get the number as result. for example:

`system("cat "4-3)` should work for your "1" case as well.  to see the difference, you could name a file as "1+1" then `system("cat "1+1)` won't work, it will complain that file "2" doesn't exist.

for the "one" example:  the 'one' in your system() worked not like string "one" but a variable named "one". in awk, if a variable was not assigned, its default value is empty string.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, awk interprets `1` as a literal 1 and `one` as a variable which has no value. That means `system` is trying to execute `cat {empty}` or `cat ''`.

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{one = "one" ; system("cat " one)}'
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{system("cat one")}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk, `1` has the value of `1` and the variable named `one` is an empty string.  So `"cat" 1` is the string `cat 1`, but `"cat" one` is the string `cat`.  The string `"cat '\''" one "'\''"` is the string `cat ''`, so you are passing the empty string as the first argument to cat.